# Python задача цикл for

Tags: python, python-3.x, for

На вход программе подается три натуральных числа `m`,`p`,`n`:

- `m` - стартовое количество организмов;
- `p` - среднесуточное увеличение в %;
- `n` - количество дней для размножения.

Напишите программу, которая предсказывает размер популяции организмов. Программа должна выводить размер популяции в каждый день, начиная с **1** и заканчивая **n-м** днем.

Формат входных данных

На вход программе подается три натуральных числа.

Формат выходных данных

Программа должна вывести текст в соответствии с условием задачи.

**Sample Input 1:**

```
10
50
6
```

**Sample Output 1:**

```
1 10.0 
2 15.0
3 22.5
4 33.75
5 50.625
6 75.9375
```

**Код:**

```
m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
d = m
for i in range(n):
    i += 1
    print(i, float(d))
    d += m / p
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.

Comment: Уберите из цикла увеличение i  - это сделает сам цикл for. Вы знаете, что такое проценты?

Comment: `d = d * (1+ p/100)` или `d = m * ((1+p/100) ** n)` без цикла

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас практически всё правильно, кроме вот этой строки:

```
d += m / p
```

Вам нужно увеличить `d` на 50% в вашем случае. Подумайте - что такое "увеличить на 50%" по сути. Переведите это в обычные дроби.
Подсказка: увеличить число на 100% - это всё-равно, что умножить число в 2 раза (или добавить к числу это же число).
И вам конечно надо сразу забыть про стартовое число `m`, все дальнейшие расчёты в цикле идут от текущего значения популяции `d`.

Answer (score 2):

Код работающий быстрее, без лишней переменной d:

```
m, p, n = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
for i in range(n):
    print(i + 1, m)
    m = m + m * (p / 100)
```

И немного упрощённое решение, хотя многим и не отличается:

```
m, p, n = float(input()), float(input()), int(input())
[print(i + 1, m * (1 + p / 100) ** (i)) for i in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def collon_mo(m,n,p):
    s = {}
    count = (100+p)/100
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        m *= count
        g = round(m,2)
        s.setdefault(i,g)
  print(s)
  return(True)

m = int(input('Enter start volume MO in colony: \n'))
n = int(input('Enter day number:  \n'))
p = int(input('Enter evaluation of collon in %:  \n'))

collon_mo(m,n,p)
```

вот такой код через функцию с выводом в словарь.
можно потом по ключам доставать нужные количества, ключи - дни.
Можно еще через цикл while...